# Issue with Javascript validation

Tags: javascript

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{
    header("location:account.php");
    die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Catch-22</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var u=document.forms["registration"]["username"].value;
var p=document.forms["registration"]["password"].value;
var p2=document.forms["registration"]["password2"].value;
var e=document.forms["registration"]["email"].value;
var c=document.forms["registration"]["college"].value;
var f=document.forms["registration"]["phone"].value;


if (u==null || u=="")
  {
  alert("Enter a Username");
  return false;
  }
 if (p==null || p=="")
  {
  alert("Enter a Password");
  return false;
  }
  if (p2==null || p2=="")
  {
  alert("Enter Password again");
  return false;
  }

  if(p!=p2)
  {
     alert("Password do not match");
     return false;
  }

  if (e==null || e=="")
  {
  alert("Enter a Email");
  return false;
  }

    var atpos=e.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=e.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=e.length)
    {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }

  if (c==null || c=="")
  {
  alert("Enter a College Name");
  return false;
  }
  if (f==null || f=="")
  {
  alert("Enter a Phone");
  return false;
  }

  if(!isInteger(f))
  {
      return false;
  }
  if(f.length<10)
  {
    alert("Phone number should have 10 digits");  
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }



 function isInteger(s)
{
      var i;
    s = s.toString();
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
      {
         var c = s.charAt(i);
         if (isNaN(c)) 
       {
        alert("Phone number should be integer");
        return false;
       }
      }
      return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="catch-b">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="catch-l">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="star"></li>
                        <li><a href="register.php">REGISTER</a></li>
                        <li class="star"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="reg">LOGIN</div>
            </div>
            <a id="catch" href="index.php"></a>
            <div id="catch-r">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="star"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>
                        <li class="star"></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="scr">TOP SCORES</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="register">
        <div class="content" id="reg-form">
        <form name="registration" method="post" action="reg.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" >
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Retype</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="password" name="password2" /></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Email</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="text" name="email"/></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>College</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="text" name="college" /></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Mobile</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="text" name="phone" /></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="2"><input name="submit" class="new-button gradient" type="submit" value="REGISTER" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
      </div>
        <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="scores-wrap">
        <div id="scores">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr><th align="left">Username</th><th align="right">Points</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Tharun</td><td align="right">09</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Jilson</td><td align="right">09</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Jismon</td><td align="right">08</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Binish</td><td align="right">07</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tobin</td><td align="right">06</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Anoop</td><td align="right">05</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="shadow2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Thanks, I got the problem fixed.

Comment: 1) Your code is open to SQL injection. Try entering `O'brien` as the user name. 2) Never ever trust javascript validated input.

Comment: How can I avoid that by changing the code in `reg.php` ?

Comment: to avoid SQL injection add a process on the code that receives the data and make sure that your application is receiving the characters for the data that it only needs avoiding such characters as " ', -- etc " regular expression would work best for this. ;)

Comment: @Jilson: [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) might be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below statement in your new page. Value of name attribute is different from original one. In the original it was "username" but in the new it is "name".

```
<tr><td>Name</td><td>:</td><td colspan="2" class="form-input"><input type="text"    
name="name" /></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Yeah, validation error fixed... But the php registration is not happening!

Comment: @JilsonThomas  I am sorry, I can not help you with the php code. I don't know much about php.

Comment: It's okay. I hope somebody can help me to figure out the problem!

Comment: @JilsonThomas  Try this. Add "return true;" at the end of your Javascript function (validateForm() ) that validates your form